# Google Python API: httplib2 SSL certificate verify failed on mac OSX (10.8.4)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use Google Custom Search python API on mac OSX (10.8.4). In particular I am trying to replicate this [sample code](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/customsearch/main.py):

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():
  service = build("customsearch", "v1",
            developerKey="some_key")

  res = service.cse().list(
      q='lectures',
      cx='some_num:some_lfve',
    ).execute()
  pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

However, while calling the **build** method, I keep getting the following httplib2 SSL error (full traceback):

```
1 service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey="some_key")

anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.pyc in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    135         else: # IGNORE
    136           pass
--> 137       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    138     return positional_wrapper
    139 

anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.pyc in build(serviceName, version, http, discoveryServiceUrl, developerKey, model, requestBuilder, credentials)
    194   logger.info('URL being requested: GET %s' % requested_url)
    195 
--> 196   resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
    197 
    198   if resp.status == 404:

anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.pyc in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
   1606                     content = ""
   1607                 else:
-> 1608                     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1609         except Exception, e:
   1610             if self.force_exception_to_status_code:

anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.pyc in _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1348             auth.request(method, request_uri, headers, body)
   1349 
-> 1350         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1351 
   1352         if auth:

anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.pyc in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1270             try:
   1271                 if hasattr(conn, 'sock') and conn.sock is None:
-> 1272                     conn.connect()
   1273                 conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
   1274             except socket.timeout:

anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.pyc in connect(self)
   1057                 # something else (such as SSL protocol mismatch).
   1058                 if e.errno == ssl.SSL_ERROR_SSL:
-> 1059                     raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
   1060                 else:
   1061                     raise

SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Any idea how I can fix this certificate issue?